# asp.net swagger specify object type

Tags: asp.net, swagger

I have the following class

```
public class UpdateUserRequest
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

And I have the following endpoint:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("/[controller]/update/user/{userId}")]
public IActionResult Update(UpdateUserRequest update, string userId)
{
    // code logic to update a user
    // etc...
}
```

If I run my project with that code swagger generates the proper documentation. The problem is that I want to modify my endpoint and instead of taking a `UpdateUserRequest update` I will like to take a `object update`. In other words this is how I would like my endpoint to look like:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("/[controller]/update/user/{userId}")]
public IActionResult Update(object update, string userId)
{
    // code logic to update a user
    // etc...
}
```

**The reason why I want to accept an `object` instead of an `UpdateUserRequest` is because I will like to enable my API to only update the properties that are sent through the request**. In other words if the user sends:

```json
{ "FirstName":"Tono" }
```

Then I will only update the property FirstName. without making the other properties null!

**How can I tell swagger to generate documentation as if the method where to take `UpdateUserRequest` parameter when in fact it is accepting an object?** When I place an object as a parameter swagger displays this:

[image]

**How can I have it display json with the format of a `UpdateUserRequest`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I have found is to do something like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{         
    // if its an update?
    if (context.Request.Method == "PUT")
    {
        // enable buffering in order to see raw object
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
       
        using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        // save body to memory
        await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        
        // convert it to json
        var rawJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

        // save raw json on current context. 
        context.Items.Add("rawJson", rawJson);

        // later that json could be from current context
        
        // reset the position
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    }
   
    await next();

);
```

But this is kind of an ugly hack when I just need a different swagger documentation.